# probability df of Y and expected value of Y

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $Y =2(X-1)^2 - 1$, where $X$ is uniformly distributed over the interval $[0,2]$. Determine the pdf of $Y$ and the expected value of $Y$.

so the pdf is like $f_Y(x)=\frac{f_Y}{2}$? right? and so i get $\frac{2(X-1)^2-1}{2}$? is this the right start?

Answer (score 0):

${\begin{align}
\text{Given:}
\\[1ex]
f_X(x) & = \frac 1 2 \; \mathbf 1_{[0,2]}(x)
\\[2ex]
Y & = \left(2(X-1)^2 -1\right)\; \mathbf 1_{[0,2]}(X)
\\[1ex]
\text{By inversion:}& \;\text{Note that there are two possible $X$ values corresponding to each $Y$ value.}
\\[1ex]X_1 & = \left(1 - \sqrt{(Y+1)/2\;}\right) \; \mathbf 1_{[-1,1]}(Y)
\\[1ex]X_2 & = \left(1 + \sqrt{(Y+1)/2\;}\right) \; \mathbf 1_{(-1,1]}(Y)
\\[2ex] \text{Now use:} & \text{ the Change of Variables Transformation, and Law of Total Probability}
\\[1ex]
f_Y(y) 
& = \left|\frac{\mathrm d x_1}{\mathrm d y}\right|f_X(x_1) + \left|\frac{\mathrm d x_2}{\mathrm d y}\right|f_X(x_2) 
\end{align}}$